# Why "label.tag" in {{ attribute.label.tag }} does not work in django template? How can we get the label of a column in template?

Tags: django, django-templates

It is possible to get the value from views.py in template in django.
It does not work to get the label and then its value. What is the way to get it?

in modules.py

```
class Article(models.Model):
    pub_date = models.DateField()
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    content = models.TextField()
    reporter = models.ForeignKey(Reporter, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.headline
```

in views.py

```
def articlesindex(request):    
    data = Articles.objects.all().last()
    return render(request, 'Articles\index.html', {'articles':data}
```

in index.html

```
{{ articles.headline }} //gives you the value
{{ articles.headline.label_tag }} //does not give you the name "headline"
```

Answer (score 1):

The attribute is [`label_tag`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.BoundField.label_tag), with an underscore.

Comment: No, well I didn't notice that you didn't have a form. Labels are for forms.